# Select nodes which are in path for print

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a problem where my page is in the background for a special print view. I would like to mark my print view container with a special class let's say '.print'. I am looking for a solution where I can **define a css rule where '.print' container, it's parents and children are not selected by the rule but everything else is**. This way every other dom element could get a css rule display:none.

For example I have the following mock code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

/* Hide all divs except those containing .print */
:not(:has(.print)) {
    display: none;
}

.print, .print * {
    display: unset; //!!!This part is not okay because under print there could be a child with display: block/flex or other value.
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div></div> <!-- display should be none -->
<div>c <!-- this should be block -->
    <div>b <!-- this should be block -->
        <div class="print">p <!-- this should be UNTOUCHED by the rules -->
            <div>a</div> <!-- this should be UNTOUCHED by the rules -->
        </div>
        <div></div><!-- display should be none -->
        <div></div><!-- display should be none -->
    </div>
</div>
<div></div><!-- display should be none -->

</body>
</html>
```

I would like to somehow combine the two rules without override the display property under '.print'. Could a css wizard help me out to create such a rule or ruleset to fulfill the mock example in a **generic way**?

I need to select every div where is **no** letter content(c,b,p,a)

**I want to avoid javascript if possible.**

Comment: @Pete the question is not really about how to change the view if I want to print something but how to hide everything unrelated inside the media query. This example is just a mock to represent the problem.

Comment: @Pete I am asking if there is a way to hide everything on the page and show only .print regardless if this is a print view or not.. it could be asked like: I need a css rule where I would like to hide everything on my page but not those nodes which have a specific class (.print in this case) or it's parents/children.

Comment: @Pete Yes the current rules do that but it is not efficient. What if inside '.print' there is node 'a' which already could have a display attribute set to block/flex. In that case I would need to define a rule for node 'a' to make sure it keeps block/flex in a more specific rule for example with '!important'. I would like to avoid this because instead of 'a' there could be a lot more node and a more complex view. In that case for every view I need an endless css ruleset to mark everything related to display attribute with !important which could lead to other problems.

Comment: @Pete so based on this there is no css rule that can select every node on the page but exclude .print, it's parent and children from this selection.

Comment: not sure if this is better but why not just use multiple selectors in your not: [`:not(.print, :has(.print), .print *) { display: none; }`](https://jsfiddle.net/gd9k5pvq/)

Comment: @Pete Wow that was I am looking for. Thanks, please answer my question so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the unset rule, you can add multiple selectors to your `not`:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

/* Hide all divs except those containing .print */
:not(.print, :has(.print), .print *) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>hide</div> <!-- display should be none -->
<div>c <!-- this should be block -->
    <div>b <!-- this should be block -->
        <div class="print">p <!-- this should be UNTOUCHED by the rules -->
            <div>a</div> <!-- this should be UNTOUCHED by the rules -->
        </div>
        <div>hide</div><!-- display should be none -->
        <div>hide</div><!-- display should be none -->
    </div>
</div>
<div>hide</div><!-- display should be none -->
```